# Customer eav_attribute only for a specific Country

Tags: eav, customer-attribute, ce-1.9.0.0

I successfully added a custom attribute for the customer's billing and shipping addresses.

This field is mandatory only for a specific country.
How can i set Magento CE v1.9 so that this field gets asked only if the user selects that specific country?

Answer (score 1):

Alex you can do using magento event observer

Create an event on `customer_address_save_before` ,which is c`heck current submit data have country`,
If have check  customer attribute this attribute value

```
<global>
    <events>             
        <customer_address_save_before>
            <observers>
                <yourmodule>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>yourmodule/observer</class>
                    <method>customer_address_save_before</method>
                </yourmodule>
            </observers>
        </customer_address_save_before>
 </events>
 </global>
```

In `Observer.php` file check  `customer address`  countyid and

```
<?php 
class Yourpackage_YourModule_Model_Observer
{
public function customer_address_save_before($observer-)
    $address = $observer->getCustomerAddress();
    if($address->getData('country_id')=='youcountryId'){

    }
}
```